# How to use MLKIT of the remote video of Agora Video Calling which is done on a surfaceview?

Tags: webrtc, surfaceview, agora.io, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

The question can also be said how to apply mlkit face detection on a surfaceview where agora is used to show video.

Here is the surfaceview code

```
private SurfaceView remoteVideoView;

mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler);
    
remoteVideoContainer.addView(remoteVideoView);
remoteVideoView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(remoteVideoView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, uid));
```

I want to use mlkit to detect face on the video using a tflite model

Is it possible by any means?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Agora Video Calling or SurfaceView, but you can somehow get either a `UIImage` or `CMSampleBuffer` of the video frame, then you can create an ML Kit `VisionImage` with that and call ML Kit's Face Detection API.  ML Kit's VisionExample quickstart sample app (https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample) has some examples of calling the face detection API.

Comment: thank you will try to find them

Answer (score 0):

You can convert SurfaceView pixels to a bitmap and then use ML Kit's [InputImage.fromBitmap(...)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage#fromBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)) to convert the bitmap to a ML Kit input image and pass it to the detector.

Comment: "SurfaceView pixels to a bitmap"
any resource on how to this?

Comment: You can take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy